# Visible objects in crystal report

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, report

I have a report like this:

[image]

I want to hide some example values ​​of 2 and 4

Also, I do not want my report to display in this format:

[image]

I want to be displayed in this format:

[image]

How do I do it?

instance of my report in visual studio:

[image]

Comment: This can be achieved with some database providers, if you are able to modify the query it might be possible on the database side.

Comment: @bendataclear i know that, but your point is very complex!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write a supress condition for `2 and 4`.

Assuming you have placed in details section:

go to supress part of the `Crystal Report`.

```
if (column=name2) or (column=name4)
then true
else false
```

let me know if this not your requirement.

Edit................................................................................

You have two options:

1. Create 100 detail sections and supress the detail section that is not necessary.
2. Create 100 formulas and by using `If Else` condtions write 100 columns in each formula and create `parameter` for selection of which columns need to be displayed and by using that parameter control the display of values.

   ```
   if({parameter}="name")   //first formula
   then "name"
   else if ({parameter}="family")
   then "family"

   ..
   ..
   ..
   ```

This way create 100 formulas...control the display.

Comment: right, but i have about 100 columns,i want to remove space between them,when i remove one(or more) of them.

Comment: since your requirement is picking specific columns.. then you need to do it manually..

Comment: To my knowledge when you supress you won't get any space.... post where are you placing the columns... will try to assist further.